# How can I define SCSS keyframes with JQuery where a for-loop and variables are used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I am currently trying to create an animation that fades the background into a gray. To do this I need to know what the background was before. Fortunately I can do this in Javascript/JQuery (I am doing this with JQuery as I believe it is much easier). Currently the background of the webpage changes radial-gradients over time with SCSS, but based off of the time in the animation, whenever the page is clicked, the animation will fade to gray instead.

Previously I did this with SCSS by doing:

```
@keyframes backgroundChange{

@for $i from 0 through 900{

    $percentage: $i * 0.11111111111111111111111111111111111111; 
    //defines what percentage to display a frame

    ...

    #{$percentage * 1%} {
    //This is like saying '$percentage%': ...

        @if $i < 100 {

            background: radial-gradient(ellipse at $xLeftPercent $yLeftPercent, rgba(218.75,62.5 + $i * 0.625,62.5, 0.5), transparent),
                        radial-gradient(ellipse at $xRightPercent $yRightPercent, rgba(140,80 + $i * 0.4,40, 0.5), transparent);

            ...
```

As you can see my animation fades the color and position of a radial-gradient. I want to do the same thing by fading from wherever the animation is to the gradient fading out to a gray. I'm having an issue with how to right this in JQuery. I would be replacing the same keyframe, so I would suspect it would be something like the following:

```
$.keyframe.define([{

    name: 'backgroundChange',

    for (i=0; i<=100; i++){

        `${i}%`: {background: radial-gradient(ellipse at `${xLeftPercent}` `${yLeftPercent}`, rgba(leftR + leftRStep * i,leftG + leftGStep * i,leftB + leftBStep * i, 0.5), transparent),
                              radial-gradient(ellipse at `${xRightPercent}` `${yRightPercent}`, rgba(rightR + rightRStep * i,rightG + rightGStep * i,rightB + rightBStep * i, 0.5), transparent)}

    }

}]);
```

The issue with my method is that the keyframes definition is expecting such as:

```
$.keyframe.define([{

    name: 'backgroundChange',

    '0%': ...,
    '1%': ...,

          ...,

    '100%': ...
}]);
```

I could really use the help with the syntax for this for-loop, as well as the syntax of defining the radial-gradient.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (*assuming all the variables exist in your code*)

```js
var xLeftPercent = 0,
    yLeftPercent = 0,
    leftR = 0,
    leftRStep = 1,
    leftG = 0,
    leftGStep = 1,
    leftB = 0,
    leftBStep = 1,
    xRightPercent = 0,
    yRightPercent = 0,
    rightR = 0,
    rightRStep = 1,
    rightG = 0,
    rightGStep = 1,
    rightB = 0,
    rightBStep = 1;

var keyframe = {name:'backgroundChange'},
    frames = Array(101).fill().map((v,i)=>(
    {[`${i}%`]:`{ background: radial-gradient(ellipse at ${xLeftPercent} ${yLeftPercent}, rgba(${leftR + leftRStep * i},${leftG + leftGStep * i},${leftB + leftBStep * i}, 0.5), transparent),
radial-gradient(ellipse at ${xRightPercent} ${yRightPercent}, rgba(${rightR + rightRStep * i},${rightG + rightGStep * i},${rightB + rightBStep * i}, 0.5), transparent)}`}
    ));
    
Object.assign(keyframe, ...frames);

// uncomment the following in your code
//$.keyframe.define([keyframe]);

console.log(keyframe);
```

Comment: This seems to have entirely worked except that the last line:

$.keyframe.define([keyframe]);

... is resulting in the error: 

Cannot read property 'define' of undefined. 

I inspected this object by doing console.log(keyframe) right before the line in question. The keyframe object, however, does not seem to be undefined as I can see the full object is correct in the console.

Comment: @FlamePrinz the error suggests that the `$.keyframe` is `undefined` not our variable. But i assumed from your code that the `$.keyframe` already existed as you seemed to be already using it. That part seems to belong to the https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes plugin and you need to load it before running the code.